# missing value in array after submit() form jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm newbie in jquery, I try to add a value into array before submit form, but after page reload, array value is missing, please help. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arrRecord = [];
    $("body").keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            arrRecord.push($('#hdCode').val());
            alert("before load: " + arrRecord[0]);
            $('form').submit();
        }
    });

    $(window).load(function () {
        alert("after load: " + arrRecord[0]);

    });
<script>
```

Comment: When your page is loaded, your array is initialized to an empty array.
And when you submit the form, the page is reloaded.

Comment: save it into a cookie...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yu're using the `.submit()` function to send the form data to the server. One of the things `.submit()` does is to reload the page. Any data you have gathered before subission is lost when the page is reloaded, unless the server stores it and sends it as part of the new page.

You can send data to a server using an AJAX call which will send the data without doing a `.submit()`. The page is not reloaded, and you can carry on processing with your data intact.

You need something like this:

```
$("body").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        arrRecord.push($('#hdCode').val());
        alert("before load: " + arrRecord[0]);
        $.ajax("tourURL.php", $('form').serialize(), function(data){

           // do something after sending data here.

        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the form values and submit it via java script try the below code :

```
$(function(){

$('form').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default action of form submit

//console.log($(this).serialize());

   $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
    //console.log(response);
   }, 'json');

});

}); // doc ready
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Html is stateless. In order to persist the value of the array either use a cookie and then store it in that and then on the next reload try to get the value back from the cookie. Or use Ajax to post the form as in submit the form in this way it wont be refreshed.